# Golang Redis websocket handler

Tags: go, websocket, redis

I need help with Golang websocket. I'm using Fiber with websocket and redis.

Here is the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/gofiber/websocket/v2"
    "log"
    "test4/controllers"
)

type User struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

var ctx = context.Background()

var redisClient = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr: "localhost:6379",
})

func TestSocket() fiber.Handler {
    socket := websocket.New(func(c *websocket.Conn) {
        go deliverMessages(c)
        var (
            msg []byte
            err error
        )
        for {
            if _, msg, err = c.ReadMessage(); err != nil {
                log.Println("read:", err)
                break
            }
            if err := redisClient.Publish(ctx, "chat", msg).Err(); err != nil {
                log.Println("publish:", err)
                break
            }
        }
    })
    return socket
}

func deliverMessages(c *websocket.Conn) {
    subscriber := redisClient.Subscribe(ctx, "chat")
    user := User{}
    for {
        msg, err := subscriber.ReceiveMessage(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("subscriber:", err)
            panic(err)
        }
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg.Payload), &user); err != nil {
            log.Println("Unmarshal:", err)
            panic(err)
        }

        text := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("{\"name\":\"%s\", \"email\":\"%s\"}", user.Name, user.Email))
        if err = c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, text); err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{
        Prefork:               true,
        CaseSensitive:         true,
        StrictRouting:         true,
        DisableStartupMessage: true,
        ServerHeader:          "Test v3",
    })
    app.Get("/", controllers.Home)
    app.Get("/ws", TestSocket())
    log.Fatal(app.Listen("0.0.0.0:3000"))
}
```

How to produce the error:

0. Install Redis and run `go run main.go`
1. Now open http://127.0.0.1:3000/ in two tabs
2. click open on both tabs, and then you will see OPEN on right side of browser
3. click send on both tabs and you will get SEND and RESPONSE
4. Now close one tab and on go program terminal you will see error (see attached screenshot)
5. Now publish data to chat channel on redis-cli

Here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is nil pointer `websocket.Conn` issue.

When close websocket connection, goroutine's `c *websocket.Conn` is loose data.
Pointer point nil.

**solution**

> use channel, use local redisClient var

```
func TestSocket() fiber.Handler {
    socket := websocket.New(func(c *websocket.Conn) {
        var redisClient = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{  //  <--  use local redisClient var
            Addr: "localhost:6379",
        })
        go deliverMessages(c)
        var (
            msg []byte
            err error
        )
        defer func() {
            redisClient.Close()             // <-- then close, when websocket connection close
            quitSubscribeGoRutine <- true   // <-- change true, when websocket connection close
        }()
        for {
            if _, msg, err = c.ReadMessage(); err != nil {
                log.Println("read:", err)

...

func deliverMessages(c *websocket.Conn) {
    subscriber := redisClient.Subscribe(ctx, "chat")
    user := User{}
    for {
        select {
        case <-quitSubscribeGoRutine:        //  <-- exit goroutine, when channel is true
                return
        default:
            msg, err := subscriber.ReceiveMessage(ctx)   //  <-- exit goroutine, when redisClient close 
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("subscriber:", err)
                break               //  <-- use break instead of panic
            }
            if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg.Payload), &user); err != nil {
                log.Println("Unmarshal:", err)
                panic(err)
            }

            text := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("{\"name\":\"%s\", \"email\":\"%s\"}", user.Name, user.Email))
            if err = c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, text); err != nil {
                log.Println("write:", err)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```